# How to Destroy a Parented Object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a shooting game in Unity, and the enemy looks close to a human because I have added many different shapes to make up an enemy. The problem is, when I shoot the enemy, the different shapes disappear instead of the whole enemy. Here is my collision code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) 
    {
        Destroy(other);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to delete all objects with the same tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `GameObject.transform.parent` to get the parent object of the current transform. You can read at [Transform.parent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

Do something like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) 
    {
        Destroy(other.transform.parent.gameobject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't only destroy the `Transform` component.. should rather be `Destroy(other.transform.parent.gameObject);`

Comment: Thank you so much. After I added gameObject to the end, it worked.

Comment: Yeah I missed adding gameobject in last. Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy a parented object in Unity using the Destroy method from the UnityEngine.Object class. Here's how you can use it:
using UnityEngine;

public class Example{
public GameObject parentObject;

```
private void DestroyParentObject()
{
    // Destroys the parent object and all its children
    Destroy(parentObject);
}
```

}

In this example, the Destroy method destroys the parentObject and all of its children. The Destroy method takes an object reference as its argument, which can be a reference to a GameObject, a Component, or any other UnityEngine.Object.

You can also specify a delay time in seconds before the object is destroyed, by passing a second argument to the Destroy method:

Destroy(parentObject, 5.0f);

In this example, the parentObject will be destroyed after 5 seconds.

Comment: For me, I've attached the script to a particle, so the particle destroys whatever it hits. I don't get access to the parented object. My question was, is there a way to find the parent of a specific object?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).